# What will happen to the current function call when a re-render happens due to a state update?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, function-call, rerender

I know when I set a new state by using the react hook setState the page will re-render at some point. When using react funtional components the whole component gets re-rendered.

To be more specific about my question the code below shows an example for a situation where I would like to understand what exactly happens to a function call during a re-render. Within a functional component I use a function to handle the login called handleLogin. This function gets triggered when clicking the submit button. Within the handleLogin function after an asynchronous operation (await signIn) is done if an error object is returned the error state will be updated accordingly (you can find it in the code as it is commented with: "This is the state update I mean.").

So now my question: So let's suppose this update triggers a re-render. Where will happen to the function call in the mean time or more specifically where will it be continued? I mean will the re-render cause the async operation to run again? Will the rest of the code of the function (in this case only the finally block) be executed? When it re-renders how does it know that the state should not be reassigned when the constant is defined?
I would like to understand where or how the function call continues after the rerender.

I hope my question can now be understood. So the question doesn't necessarily relate to this code, the code is just an example.

```
export default function Login() {

    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const router = useRouter()

    type Credentials = {
        email: string
        password: string
    }

    const handleLogin = async (credentials: Credentials) => {

        if (!credentials.email) {
            return setError('email is missing')
        }
        if (!credentials.password) {
            return setError('password is missing')
        }
        try {
            const response: SignInResponse | undefined = await signIn('credentials', { ...credentials, redirect: false })
            if (response?.error && response.error === 'CredentialsSignin') {
                setError('email or password are wrong') //This is the state update I mean.
            } else {
                setError('')
                router.push('/')
            }
        } catch {
            setError('login failed')
        } finally {
            formik.setSubmitting(false)
        }
    }

    return (...)
}
```

Comment: **So you can basicly ignore all the Formik/Yup stuff.** Don't include unrelated code in your example. Please read [mre]. Also, it's probably a good idea to format the wall-of-text a bit more reader-friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where will happen to the function call in the mean time or more
> specifically where will it be continued?

The function `handleLogin` will finish execution before the component is re-rendered. When `setError` is called, React will enqueue the update / render and perform it "later".

---

> I mean will the re-render cause the async operation to run again?

No

---

> Will the rest of the code of the function (in this case only the
> finally block) be executed?

Yes

---

> When it re-renders how does it know that the state should not be
> reassigned when the constant is defined?

You'll have to read the source code of React to get a precise answer. React tracks state values by the order in which `useState` is called.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering question by question. Your first answer confuses me even more. In a older version of this code I had another state called loading which was set to true at the start of the handleLogin function in order to render a spinner while the login was handled, at the end of the handleLogin function the state was set to false again in order for the spinner to disappear. So considering your first answer this behaviour would be impossible if the re-render happens only AFTER the entire function was executed. Am I wrong and if so why or how? :)

Comment: The handleLogin returns a Promise immediately, since it is async. The code following `await` will be executed later and fulfill that Promise.

Comment: Just to understand you correctly, let me bring up another example. If I have a function with the following structure in her body: set state to true which triggers spinner to appear, some code to be exectued, set state  to false which triggers the spinner to disappear again. Your answer would suggest that the spinner would never appear as the whole function will be executed and then the rerender happens in which the state would be false.  Is that right?

Comment: functions are only called based on events, for example, click events, component load events and so on